# Javascript change DISPLAY:NONE to BLOCK on clientside - PHP/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?PHP
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        if($i < 1){
            printf("<div style='display:block' id='id-$i'>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
        }else{
            printf("<div style='display:none' id='id-$i'>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
        }
        $i= $i+1;
    }

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // store state that we can update
    var currentVisible = 0;
    // function to update the state and display
    function change() {
        // hide the old item
        document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'none';
        // update the current index
        currentVisible++;
        // show the new item
        document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'block';

        // if we're not showing the last item, queue another change
        if (currentVisible < 5)
            setTimeout(change, 8000);
    }

    // queue the first change
    setTimeout(change, 8000);
</script>
```

My case: The "PHP while" is writing "DISPLAY NONE" in all results excepts the first.

The problems:
1. When it shows the last result of Mysql it should return to the first

Comment: There is no sleep() function in JavaScript so unless you have another file that includes this function then the loop will not execute.

Comment: Can you please help? I'm tottaly lost

Answer (score 1):

`sleep(5000)` (even if it did exist in JavaScript) is not what you would want. Basically, `sleep` would cause the thread to freeze and not do ANYTHING (including render the page) until the time had elapsed (assuming it were a mirror of PHP's `sleep`). In JavaScript, you want to think in more of an event-driven model.

```
// store state that we can update
var currentVisible = 0;
// function to update the state and display
function change() {
  // hide the old item
  document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'none';
  // update the current index
  currentVisible++;
  // show the new item
  document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'block';

  // if we're not showing the last item, queue another change
  if (currentVisible < 4)
    setTimeout(change, 5000);
}

// queue the first change
setTimeout(change, 5000);
```

```
<?PHP
  $i = 0;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $i= $i+1;
    if ($i > 1) {
      // purely numeric ids aren't valid and some browsers don't allow them, be sure to include some string portion
      printf("<div style='display:none' id='id-$i'>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }else{
      printf("<div style='display:block' id='id-$i'>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }
  }
?>
```

**Update after question rewrite:**

If you want the updates to happen forever, use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` for the last line of the JavaScript section, remove the `if (...) setTimeout(...);` from the end of the `change` function, and change the state update from `currentVisible++` to `currentVisible = (currentVisible + 1) % 5;`.

Comment: Didn't work isn't very descriptive.  Is it throwing an error?  Yielding incorrect results?

Comment: Try to provide more helpful comments. "Didn't work. Why?" is not a question which makes me likely to respond positively. I'm not sure why it might not have worked for you, but here is an example of the code your PHP file should generate, using the JavaScript I proposed and it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/65hTh/  If it takes more than 25 seconds for your database to load the rows it is displaying (which would be ridiculous), then move the script block to after the `<div>` generation.

Comment: When I check CODE of website everything are there BUT it is not changing. I'm trying to check what is happening